# Cannot get Java Applets to work in any browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla

We are trying to download something from GE that uses Java to download when logging into the site.  This is a windows 7 Professional PC.  I have other computers that are able to do this successfully.  Here is my order of operations:

1. Log into the site and select the file I want to download
2. Click download
3. It takes me to the page that says it will start in a few seconds but nothing happens.  It is supposed to have a box that asks for Java to run.

I have reinstalled Java fresh and still nothing.  Tried with multiple user accounts.  Added the site to the list of exceptions in the firewalls and Java configuration.  I have tried an earlier version of Java.  This happens in Mozilla, Chrome and IE.  I have made sure that the Java plugin shows up and is enabled.  I just cant think of what I am missing.  And since we are a contractor GE is not going to help us.  Can anyone here think of anything?

Comment: This question is likely to be off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the Java plugin enabled? e.g. in Firefox, go to Settings, Plugins, and change Java Platform SE8 'Next Generation Java Plugin' to 'always activate'?

Comment: Yes I did have it set to Always Active.  One of the things I did see is that the Toolbox Add-in cannot change but I figured that was normal.  The regular Java Platform one is Always Activate

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to the issues I had with Cisco WebVPN, Java-style.  Once you have Java installed correctly and set as a plugin for any of the browsers you would like to use, see below.

Before you even start looking at browsers - if you think it is already set up correctly

1. Look at your Anti-Virus programs or anything else that could prevent it from working.  McAfee *Host Intrusion Protection* is known to cause many Java programs to fail.  Kapersky had issues, a while back, with Java on Windows ([Java Applets not loading in Windows 8](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/java-applets-not-loading-in-windows-8/ed85be04-6792-469b-9b77-7829951adb2c) ).
2. You must have a 64-bit browser to use 64-bit Java (also mentioned in the Chrome link below).

See below for any specific things that can be modified in the browser.

---

**Chrome 43** is the more complicated browser to set up.  They have a dedicated page with instructions.

[How do I use Java with the Google Chrome browser?](http://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml)

---

**Firefox 38** will prompt you.

[image]

---

In **Internet Explorer 11**, it's under *Internet Options->Security*.  I recommend adding the hostname the applet is on as a Trusted Site (Select *Trusted Sites* and click the *Sites* button, then add the first part of the url).  Click the Custom level button and make sure that *Scripting of Java applets* is not disabled.

[image: IE security settings]

If you still have problems with the applet:

1. Verify your Java version will work with the applet you are accessing
2. Verify the plugin is enabled for the browser through the Java Control Panel, which is available in Windows Control Panel, or on Mac/Linux, execute it from the JDK directory ($JAVA_HOME/ControlPanel ).

Comment: I checked Antivirus which is Symantec and added the site and Java to list of exceptions.  I have also completely disabled it and the Windows Firewall and still does not work.  I also check the setting in IE for Scripting of Java Applets and it is set to enable.  I was able to verify the java version from the Java website

Comment: I also verified that the Java in the control Panel is set to be on.  Whats messed up is that the window you get in the firefox screen does not show up on my screen and I will throw something else at you, There is a troubleshooting page provided by GE on the page when it tries to download.  When I click the troubleshooting it opens a separate tab and when it is opening there is a Java Applet on the left for what I am guessing is a directory but it doesn't load and the page crashes and I have to close the tab.

Comment: If you can go to the Java version verify page ( http://www.java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp?detect=jre) using the same browser and the plugin starts up and runs ok, then it's unlikely to be an issue with your plugin or browser configuration, so the issue is sounding like the applet you are trying to run... It sounds like this is a third party app, you really should reach out to the vendor for help?

Comment: They wont provide any support because we are a contractor so they wont even talk to me.  Im trying to figure out why it works on some other computers just fie but not this one.  I have confirmed everything is allowed through just like this one and the settings are the same and even the versions are messing up.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the issue.  I had to allow their UK site on the list for Java and enable the SSL 2.0 for HTTP in Java config as well